# PID Creation Time

Tags: winapi

I was looking for a way to figure out what time the PID was created/most-recently-claimed. I was able to get it with `NtQuerySystemInformation` however it seems intensive just to get the time a PID was claimed. Is there any very quick way to get this info?

I tried `CreateToolhelp32Snapshot` -> `Process32First`, this way is very fast, but it doesn't give me the PID creation time.

Thanks

This is the info available to me from NtQuerySystemInformation is this structure below, it gives me `UniqueProcessId` and also `CreateTime`

http://processhacker.sourceforge.net/doc/struct___s_y_s_t_e_m___p_r_o_c_e_s_s___i_n_f_o_r_m_a_t_i_o_n.html

_SYSTEM_PROCESS_INFORMATION Struct

```
ULONG   NextEntryOffset
ULONG   NumberOfThreads
LARGE_INTEGER   WorkingSetPrivateSize
ULONG   HardFaultCount
ULONG   NumberOfThreadsHighWatermark
ULONGLONG   CycleTime
LARGE_INTEGER   CreateTime
LARGE_INTEGER   UserTime
LARGE_INTEGER   KernelTime
UNICODE_STRING  ImageName
KPRIORITY   BasePriority
HANDLE  UniqueProcessId
HANDLE  InheritedFromUniqueProcessId
ULONG   HandleCount
ULONG   SessionId
ULONG_PTR   UniqueProcessKey
SIZE_T  PeakVirtualSize
SIZE_T  VirtualSize
ULONG   PageFaultCount
SIZE_T  PeakWorkingSetSize
SIZE_T  WorkingSetSize
SIZE_T  QuotaPeakPagedPoolUsage
SIZE_T  QuotaPagedPoolUsage
SIZE_T  QuotaPeakNonPagedPoolUsage
SIZE_T  QuotaNonPagedPoolUsage
SIZE_T  PagefileUsage
SIZE_T  PeakPagefileUsage
SIZE_T  PrivatePageCount
LARGE_INTEGER   ReadOperationCount
LARGE_INTEGER   WriteOperationCount
LARGE_INTEGER   OtherOperationCount
LARGE_INTEGER   ReadTransferCount
LARGE_INTEGER   WriteTransferCount
LARGE_INTEGER   OtherTransferCount
SYSTEM_THREAD_INFORMATION   Threads [1]
```

Comment: What information do you have available? Will GetProcessTimes() work for you?

Comment: Thanks @CodyGray I added to the post the info I get Ill search that function right away.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given a Process ID, use [`OpenProcess()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684320.aspx) to get a `HANDLE` to the process, then use [`GetProcessTimes()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683223.aspx) to query its times.

```
BOOL GetProcessCreationTime(DWORD dwProcessId, LPFILETIME CreationTime)
{
    BOOL bResult = FALSE;
    HANDLE hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION, FALSE, dwProcessId);
    if (hProcess)
    {
        FILETIME Ignore;
        bResult = GetProcessTimes(hProcess, CreationTime, &Ignore, &Ignore, &Ignore);
        CloseHandle(hProcess);
    }
    return bResult;
}
```

```
DWORD dwProcessId = ...;
FILETIME CreationTime;
if (GetProcessCreationTime(dwProcessId, &CreationTime))
{
    // use CreationTime as needed...
}
```

Just note that this will only be able to open the process while it is still running, or if the process has terminated but has not been fully closed yet.

**Update:** If you want to use `NtQuerySystemInformation()` instead of `GetProcessTimes()`, it would look more like this instead:

```
BOOL GetProcessCreationTime(DWORD dwProcessId, LPFILETIME CreationTime)
{
    typedef NTSTATUS (WINAPI *LPFN_NTQSI)(SYSTEM_INFORMATION_CLASS, PVOID, ULONG, PULONG);
    static LPFN_NTQSI lpNtQuerySystemInformation = NULL;

    if (!lpNtQuerySystemInformation)
    {
        lpNtQuerySystemInformation = (LPFN_NTQSI) GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandle(TEXT("ntdll.dll")), "NtQuerySystemInformation");
        if (!lpNtQuerySystemInformation)
            return FALSE;
    }

    _SYSTEM_PROCESS_INFORMATION *arr;
    ULONG ulSize = 1024;
    NTSTATUS status;

    do
    {
        arr = (_SYSTEM_PROCESS_INFORMATION*) LocalAlloc(LMEM_FIXED, ulSize);
        if (!arr)
            return FALSE;

        status = NtQuerySystemInformation(SystemProcessInformation, arr, ulSize, &ulSize); 
        if (NT_SUCCESS(status))
            break;

        LocalFree(arr);

        if (status != STATUS_INFO_LENGTH_MISMATCH)
            return FALSE;

        ulSize *= 2;
    }
    while (true);

    _SYSTEM_PROCESS_INFORMATION *process = arr;
    do
    {
        if (GetProcessId(process->UniqueProcessId) == dwProcessId)
        {
            CreationTime->dwLowDateTime = process->CreateTime.LowPart;
            CreationTime->dwHighDateTime = process->CreateTime.HighPart;
            LocalFree(arr);
            return TRUE;
        }

        if (process->NextEntryOffset == 0)
            break;

        process = (_SYSTEM_PROCESS_INFORMATION*) (((LPBYTE)process) + process->NextEntryOffset);
    }
    while (true);

    LocalFree(arr);
    return FALSE;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Remy, this is many calls, I think the `NTQueryInformation` method is more efficient no? This is a great answer though thanks I accept. I learned which is more efficient which helps me make choice.

Comment: This is only 3 calls. With `NtQuerySystemInformation()`, you have to call it once to get the byte size of an array of `SYSTEM_PROCESS_INFORMATION` entries, then you have to allocate that array and call `NtQuerySystemInformation()` again to fill it, then you have to loop through the array looking for the target process ID, and finally deallocate the array. That is much more work. Not to mention that the `Nt...()` functions access internal OS data that may change from one OS version to another. MSDN says: "*NtQuerySystemInformation may be altered or unavailable in future versions of Windows.*"

Comment: I added an `NtQuerySystemInformation()` example to my answer to show you how much more work it is.

Comment: Thanks so much @Remy - Oh I forgot to mention I needed all current PIDs. I wanted to use `CreateToolhelp32Snapshot` because it seemed better then iterating over them live, as between each call there is chance things change. I needed a full list of all PIDs and their creation times, and I couldnt get that from snapshot :(