# Checking if a process is running perpetually

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm currently making an app in cpp,and I need to perpetually check if 2 apps are running ,and I got A solution but its a bit bad because I ran that function every 4ms, the function in question,btw I do know the names of the apps:

```
void inline isProcessRunning() {
PROCESSENTRY32 entry{};
entry.dwSize = sizeof(PROCESSENTRY32);

HANDLE snapshot = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, NULL);
if (Process32First(snapshot, &entry))
    while (Process32Next(snapshot, &entry)) {
        if (!wcsicmp(entry.szExeFile, L"App1.exe")) {
            Do something...

        }
        if (!wcsicmp(entry.szExeFile, L"App2.exe")) {
            do something...
        }
    }
CloseHandle(snapshot);
}
```

The problem with this function is the amount of syscalls its doing and because of it my app cpu usage sometimes jumps when its usually at 0%, I would like to know if there's a way to refresh the snapshot without having to create another one or another method to chech if a process is running.

Thanks in advance

Tried to use snapshots but performance is lackluster

Comment: Maybe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/872364/win32-get-message-notification-of-other-applications-close-exit

Comment: @NathanOliver I want to check when it opens and it closes,because that might happend multiple times during my program execution

Comment: Can your application just start the other 2 applications instead of constantly monitoring that they are running?

Comment: @drescherjm No, it should only execute their functions IF those apps are opened by the user,and when they're closed they should stop doing what they're doing

Comment: Is it possible that there will be more than one instance of `App1.exe` or `App2.exe` running?

Comment: @AndreasWenzel The apps are emulators so probably not,even if there is ,its irrelevant,I am changing my dualsense triggers when Yuzu or Dolphin opens,so it doesnt matter if 1 or 1 million of instances are opened as long as I can detect 1 with low cpu usage

edit: I also tried to see if when opened those apps would create something and delete on closing but nop....

Comment: This is the [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info). Please ask about the problem you are trying to solve, not your imagined solution (plot spoiler: it isn't).

Comment: not use CreateToolhelp32Snapshot, Process32First, Process32Next in any case. it have terrible implementation, which visible degrade perfomance.  use NtQuerySystemInformation direct. and of course, are need poll at all

Comment: Not sure if its overhead is better, you can try [Receiving Event Notifications Through WMI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmisdk/example--receiving-event-notifications-through-wmi-). [__InstanceCreationEvent class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmisdk/--instancecreationevent#remarks)

Answer (score 3):

> I would like to know if there's a way to refresh the snapshot without having to create another one

No, there is not.

> or another method to chech if a process is running

Once your polling has detected a desired app is running, then stop polling for that app. You have its current PID, so you can simply *open that process* with `OpenProcess()` and then wait on it with `WaitForSingleObject()` or other related function. That will tell you when the process ends.  Then you can start polling for that app again to detect when it begins running again

Alternatively, use a [`PsSetCreateProcessNotifyRoutine()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/ntddk/nf-ntddk-pssetcreateprocessnotifyroutine) callback, which *tells* you when a process begins and ends.

Comment: Be sure to check the process name again immediately after `OpenProcess()`, just in case the PID was reused in between creation of the snapshot and opening the handle.

Comment: @BenVoigt indeed!

Comment: @BenVoigt [Process creation time](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-getprocesstimes) is probably a better predicate to validate process identity against a snapshot. It's cheaper and immune to a binary getting renamed while executing.

Comment: @IInspectable and what are you going to compare it against initially? The snapshot does not provide timestamps. What Ben is describing is when the snapshot is taken and then the process ends and its PID is reused before it can be opened by the code that took the snapshot. The only usable identifier in that case is the file name

Comment: *"and what are you going to compare it against initially?"* - A timestamp taken just before the call to `CreateToolhelp32Snapshot()`. If process creation time predates this timestamp, the PID can be trusted. False negatives are no more of an issue than they are when comparing path names. False positives do not exist. The latter isn't true when comparing path names.

Comment: @IInspectable but then you run into the problem of detecting new processes that are created after the initial timestamp is taken and the time the snapshot is taken.  Perhaps consider using `NtQuerySystemInformation()` instead of `CreateToolhelp32Snapshot()`, that way you get the PIDs *and* the creation times together in a single iteration. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34705739/

Comment: *"then you run into the problem of \[...\]"* - This reads like the situation got worse when really it didn't. If you poll, you **must** be prepared to miss events that fall in between sampling points. My comment proposed a strategy that eliminates false positives. I don't understand what problem `NtQuerySystemInformation()` is intended to solve here.